# ActiveForm Как объединить checkboxlist и textinput в одно поле?

Tags: php, yii2

Имеется checkboxlist/radiobuttonlist с вариантами ответа. Последний вариант ответа должен быть с собственным вариантом ответа, который пишется вручную

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант ответа уходит в модель и сохраняется в общую таблицу:

```
id | id_answer | id_user |
```

где `id_answer` - айди выбранного ответа из таблицы answers (`id|text_answer`).

`id_user` - собственно айдишник юзера, которому принадлежит ответ

Вот стандартный чекбокслист:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'id_answer')->
    checkboxList(Answers::find()->select(['text_answer', 'id_answer ])->
    indexBy('id_asnwer')->column(), ?>
```

Как дополнить его собственным вариантом ответа?

p.s: собственные ответы юзера планируется сохранять в тужу таблицу `answers` , но выводить для варианта ответа только заранее подготовленные. (или можно по-другому?)

Comment: а как вы хотите сохранять свой ответ без поля в базе для этого ответа?

Comment: @MasterAlex сначала в таблицу `Answers`, там присвоить ему айдишник и оттуда в общую таблицу. Или как лучше то вообще?

Comment: я имею ввиду сам текст сообщения, если вы хотите его сохранять, то нужно делать поле для этого, а если не хотите, то просто также как и другие поля по id, а для текстового поля вывести обычный input без какой-либо привязки к модели :)

Comment: @MasterAlex Ну ясно понятно, но как это сделать? Например, чтобы при radiolist нельзя было ввести туда текст, пока не будет поставлена галка на неё. (как на картинке)
Мне код формы нужен. Примеров найти не могу

Comment: Добавить в таблицу поле text_answer. Если человек выбрал "Другой", то id_answer оставить null. Реализовать логику можно напрямую. Вовсе не обязательно городить все ActiveForm'ами и запихивать все в рамки фреймворка.

Comment: @ZhiV, добавляете текстовое поле под радиобаттонами, которое не будет required, а дальше можно через Javascript показывать блок с этим полем, когда выбран определённый radiobutton. Следовательно, пока юзер не выберет пункт "другое", это текстовое  поле не будет видно, вот и вся логика. Естественно это поле должно быть в базе, но оно будет пустое, когда будут выбирать другие пункты